# Elixir: How to write Enum.map in block instead of Anonymous function?

Tags: elixir

I have function which results me keyword list, I wanted to write mutiple lines of code before calling scraper function, how I can write this in block using map?

```
Enum.map(elements, fn(x) -> Scraper.Abc.markup(x) end)
```

I wanted to write many code lines, I can use for loop but it will not result me anything

```
for elements <- x do
 x
 |> ...
 |> ...
 |> ...
 |> Scraper.Abc.markup
end
```

Any help?

Comment: Why not just `Enum.map(elements, fn(x) -> x |> ... |> ... |> ... |> Scraper.Abc.markup() end)`? Also as a side note, that is not a for loop, while it looks like one, it is called a list comprehension, and it will return a value.

Comment: Could you update your question to show your exact input and desired output? It's not clear currently what you're asking.

Comment: @JustinWood i wanted to split into block because fn(x) -> x |> ... |> ... |> ... |>  will be too lon if I have many functions to run

Comment: [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#for/1) does indeed exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to write mutiple lines of code before calling scraper function,

```
defmodule A do
  def go do

    list = Enum.map([1, 2, 3], fn(x) -> 
      IO.puts "hello #{x}"
      str = String.upcase("goodbye #{x}")
      spawn(fn -> IO.puts str end)
      {:result, 2*x}
    end)

    IO.puts "list = #{inspect list}"

  end
end
```

In iex:

```
iex(1)> A.go     
hello 1
GOODBYE 1
hello 2
GOODBYE 2
hello 3
GOODBYE 3
list = [result: 2, result: 4, result: 6]
:ok
```

Or, you can do this:

```
defmodule A do
  def go do
    list = Enum.map([1, 2, 3], &my_func/1)
    IO.puts "list = #{inspect list}"
  end

  def my_func(x) do
    IO.puts "hello #{x}"
    str = String.upcase("goodbye #{x}")
    spawn(fn -> IO.puts str end)
    {:result, 2*x}
  end

end
```

In iex:

```
iex(5)> A.go
hello 1
GOODBYE 1
hello 2
GOODBYE 2
hello 3
GOODBYE 3
list = [result: 2, result: 4, result: 6]
:ok
```

> I can use for loop but it will not result me anything

```
defmodule A do
  def go do

    list = for x <- [1, 2, 3] do
      x
      |> IO.inspect()
      |> Kernel.+(10)
      |> IO.inspect(label: "+10")
      |> Kernel.*(3)
      |> IO.inspect(label: "*3")
      |> do_stuff()
    end

    IO.puts "list = #{inspect list}"
  end

  def do_stuff(x), do: {:result, x * 100}
end
```

In iex:

```
iex(3)> A.go     
1
+10: 11
*3: 33
2
+10: 12
*3: 36
3
+10: 13
*3: 39
list = [result: 3300, result: 3600, result: 3900]
:ok
```

Comment: @VishalG  `attentions`  => `intentions`

Answer (score 2):

Since for some reason you are not satisfied with a comprehension (why?) I would go with producing a helper function and using it in map.

```rb
defmodule Utils do
  def do_stuff(x) do
    x
    |> ...
    |> ...
    |> ...
    |> ...
    |> Scraper.Abc.markup()
  end
end

Enum.map(elements, &Utils.do_stuff/1)
```