# Elixir: How to push map into Array/list?

Tags: elixir

I have 1 function which I call mutliple times, I wanted to call this function multiple times and put into array/list

```
  def markup(element) do
    {
      :title, title(element)
    }
  end
```

In ruby we do like this

```
list = []
list << {title: 1}
list << {title: 2}
```

Any similar way in Elixir?

Comment: Your first example produces a map containing `title` and `source` keys. Your second example is a list of maps containing the same `identifier` and `source` keys. Your third example produces a list with different maps, one containing `x` key and one containing `y` key . It would help if your example and desired output were consistent.

Comment: Also, a keyword list is a list of tuples where the first element in each tuple is an `:atom`, but your example is a list of hashes. Which do you want? I guess this is also related to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57189110/elixir-how-to-write-enum-map-in-block-instead-of-anonymous-function).

Comment: @AdamMillerchip my bad updated questions

Comment: _Sidenote:_ doing this in Ruby is a very bad practice as well. One should use map/reduce rather than create an array upfront and fill it that way.

Answer (score 3):

Values are immutable in Elixir. So there is no operator like `<<` that would modify an existing list. You may want to use [`Keyword.put/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Keyword.html#put/3) for this.

```
list =
  []
  |> Keyword.put(:x, 1)
  |> Keyword.put(:y, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of your ruby sample in elixir would be:

```
list = []
list = [{:x, 1} | list]
list = [{:y, 2} | list]
```

Comment: It won’t be the equivalent of the ruby sample, though. Yours _prepends_ to the list, the ruby one _appends_.

Comment: additionnaly your not mutating the list but returning a new one

Comment: @ConstantinGuidon variables are immutable in elixir, so this comes closest to an equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

In Elixir, we can do the `++` operator to append a list to another list:

```
list = []
list ++ [{:title, 3}, {:title, 4}]
```

**Take note: This approach takes linear time, which is slower compared to the cons operator which takes O(1) time, but it prepends to the beginning of array.**

```
list = []
list = [{:title, 3} | list]
```